# Создание проверка имеет ли товар видимость "Личное"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет.

Столкнулась с такой задачей, что нужно проверить имеет ли товар видимость "Личное", т.е. показывается только администраторам и редакторам. В гугле, к сожалению, ничего похожего не смогла найти. Буду рада любой помощи :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это обычный статус поста (`private`), поэтому вам нужно проверять именно его.
для товара это можно сделать вот так:
global $product;

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $product->get_status() );
echo '</pre>';
```

метод `get_status` вернет вам `private` для приватных товаров